# Python does not recognize the module

Tags: python, module, pycharm, package

I know it is a very common problem and I tried some solutions here but it did not work. I have this structure

```
Document
cnn (package)
  src (package)
    config(package)
    dataloader(package)
    dataset(package)
    models(package)
    trainer(package)
    utils(package)
    main.py # [ here I have this import: from cnn.src.config import X, Y
```

I got this error:

**from cnn.src.config import X, Y
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cnn'**

The code is running very well on pycharm but It does not run on terminal!! Could someone explain a little bit the problem or refer me to a source to understand this headache !

Answer (score 0):

The PYTHONPATH in your terminal environment doesn't contain 'cnn' directory.

[Configure the PYTHONPATH to include the directory containing your module](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000058690-Module-not-found-in-PyCharm-but-externally-in-Python)

It works in PyCharm because it sets up the path for you.

Comment: I am under `Document` and I run `export PYTHONPATH="$PWD/cnn/"`  . I try to run `main.py` from different pathes but still the same problem
`